# Canonical transformation for hamiltonian system possessing first integral

Tags: hamilton-equations, canonical-transformation

Let say I have a Hamiltonian system
$$
\begin{align*}
 \dot p &= -H_q \\
 \dot q &= H_p
\end{align*}
$$ with Hamiltonian $H(p,q)$, coordinates $q \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and momenta $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$. I know, that the system possesses a first integral $f(p, q)$: $\{f, H\} = 0$.

Am I right, that there exists a canonical transformation $(p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2) \mapsto (\xi_1, \xi_2, \eta_1, \eta_2)$ s.t. dynamics for subsystem $\xi_1, \eta_1$ are getting trivial? Something like
$$
\begin{align*}
  \dot \xi_1 &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
$$
If so, what the generating function will be?